# Disable a button when the user state changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

Im managing the user "state" of the DB with a field in the DB called isActive that could be true or false.

On my interface I have two buttons that if I press the green one this action activate the user. If I press the red one this action desactivate the user.

[image]

I have this code on my interns.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  LOAD_USERS,
  USER_ACTIVATE,
  USER_DESACTIVATE,
} from "../../components/store/reducers/usersReducer";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Users() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const router = useRouter();
  const listUsers = useSelector((state) => state.usersReducer.users);

  const [updateValues, changeUpdateValues] = React.useState({
    isActive: listUsers?.isActive,
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_USERS,
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="dataText">Usuarios Internos</h1>
        <div className="center-item">
          <div>
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>NAME</th>
                  <th>LASTNAME</th>
                  <th>EMAIL</th>
                  <th>OPTIONS</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              {listUsers &&
                listUsers.map((item) => {
                  let id = item.id;
                  const userURL = `http://localhost:3001/users/${id}`;
                  const userEditURL = `http://localhost:3001/users/intern/${id}`;

                  const buttonActivateComponent = {
                    onClick: (e) => {
                      dispatch({
                        payload: {
                          id: id,
                          isActive: updateValues.isActive,
                        },
                        type: USER_ACTIVATE,
                      });
                      router.push("/users/interns");
                    },
                    className: "activate-btn",
                  };

                  const buttonDesactivateComponent = {
                    onClick: (e) => {
                      dispatch({
                        payload: {
                          id: id,
                          isActive: updateValues.isActive,
                        },
                        type: USER_DESACTIVATE,
                      });
                      router.push("/users/interns");
                    },
                    className: "activate-btn",
                  };

                  return (
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>{item.document}</td>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td>{item.lastname}</td>
                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                        <td className="icons">
                          <a href={userURL}>
                            <i className="fas fa-info-circle icon"></i>
                          </a>
                          <a href={userEditURL}>
                            <i className="fas fa-user-edit icon"></i>
                          </a>
                          <a {...buttonActivateComponent}>
                            <i className="fas fa-power-off icon green"></i>
                          </a>
                          <a {...buttonDesactivateComponent}>
                            <i className="fas fa-power-off icon red"></i>
                          </a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  );
                })}
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have problems thinking on how could I make the button of each user disabled acording to the state that comes in the variable "isActive"

So that means if I have the first user of the table with the field isActive = true. The green button on the interface should be disabled and the red one enabled. And if I disabled this user with the red button. Then the green button should be enabled and the red one disabled.

Thanks if anyone can help me with this would be great. :)

Answer (score 0):

foremost, you have to make a row component to create a more appropriate abstraction, then in UserRow (the separated row component) create a state to store the status of the user, dependent on the state and the initial data you can decide to enable which button!

I wrote an example for you, take a look at this:

```
const testData = [
  {
    name: 'Mike',
    status: 'dead',
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    status: 'alive',
  },
  {
    name: 'Arthur',
    status: 'dead',
  },
];

function User({ name, status }) {
  const [isAlive, setIsAlive] = React.useState(
    status === 'alive' ? true : false
  );

  const toggleStatus = () => {
    setIsAlive((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{`${name} is ${isAlive ? 'alive' : 'dead'}`}</h1>
      <button onClick={toggleStatus} disabled={isAlive}>
        make him alive
      </button>
      <button onClick={toggleStatus} disabled={!isAlive}>
        kill him
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Users() {
  return (
    <div>
      {testData.map((data, index) => (
        <User name={data.name} status={data.status} key={index} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks I will study the code and see if its work on my project.